# Animate continuously onMouseover using setInterval

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I have been stuck with this problem for quite some time now and i have searched on Google for countless hours to come up with a solution but to no avail.

**Here is my Problem**

I want to know the Logic behind a Carousel and would like to make it slide from right to left or vice-versa when a user hovers on the respective buttons.

How can i make it animate continuously on mouseenter?

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank You :)

**Here is the JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/neoragex/qXseV/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your version, check it out :) http://jsfiddle.net/qXseV/2/

What I did is add the following to your css of the .mid class:

```
position:absolute;
top:20px;
```

And I changed your setInterval to:

```
timer = setInterval(function() {slide();}, 400);
```

EDIT: extra jsfiddle with both left and right movement http://jsfiddle.net/qXseV/7/

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. If its not too much trouble . Can you please tell me why my Code didnt work in the first place D: ? You declared the slide() function inside the setInterval function :O!~

Comment: First of all, it seemed necessary to me to add the position absolute of the mid. Elseway a change in position would not be work.
And then: I didn't declare the slide function in the setInterval, but I fired the function in a different way, I'm not sure why it didn't work the way you tried to fire it.

Comment: Thank YOU :) . I am fairly new at Javascript and jQuery. Does that mean, animations work only on absolutely positioned elements?

Comment: Your welcome :)
No, not necessarly. I *think* only if you'd want to change their position. If you want them to fadeIn or fadeOut for example, absolute positioning wouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so so so much XD. There are too many Carousel Plugins on the Internet but i never knew how they worked and i was trying to come up with a simple version that automated movements on Hover but i seem to get stuck in various corners <.<!~

Comment: Wahhh. I want to chat with you and gain more info on the topic. Apparently the comment column said. Avoid Extended Discussions <.<!~

Comment: Please do let me know if you have like 15 minutes of spare time to help this Newbie ^_^.

Comment: I really don't know THAT much about jquery either :) these are just some things I came across myself a little while ago. If you'd like to chat, no problem

Comment: @bjornruysen, +'d for the quick fix, but I would suggest using `position:relative;` to avoid adding extra **CSS** like the `top`.

Comment: @Zuul That indeed would be a better solution, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Yay. Thanks :). How do i chat in here xD ?. Or do i need to use an IM to chat with the members in here :) ?

Comment: I have no idea, haven't done that yet either. It sais 'chat' at the top of the page, but you'll need '20 reputation' to use it?!

Comment: @LearningSlowly, place some more questions, we help you out! In turn, you earn the necessary reputation to chat :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments at [your timer implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/dn62c/) and fixed the missing css [position:relative](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) on the element to be slided, since you are manipulating the [left value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp), that in turn can only be used if the element has a position.

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftarrow">HOVER</div>
<div class="mid"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mid {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
    position: relative;
}
#leftarrow {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
// declare variables
var timer;
var speed = 400;

// slide function
function slide() {
    return setInterval(function() {
        $(".mid").animate({
            'left': '+=20px'
        }, 200);
    }, speed);
}

// hover event for the button
$("#leftarrow").hover(function() {
    timer = slide();
}, function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

See the [Fiddle Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/dn62c/)

Comment: Wow. Thank you for pointing out that left and similar thingys can only be manipulated with the position defined. Sigh. I almost thought i had it on my first Try xD. Thank you so much ^^!~.

Comment: The W3C website gives you the basics to every **CSS** / **HTML** / **SCRIPT** property, [bookmark it](http://www.w3schools.com/w3c/default.asp) ;)