# how to use setInterval to continue animation while mouse is over div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, setinterval

I am trying to modify a slideshow to continuously animate while the mouse is over the back or next arrow. If the mouse leaves, I would like the animation to stop where it is.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331439/jquery-how-can-i-continue-an-animation-while-the-mouse-hovers-over-an-element) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512835/animate-continuously-onmouseover-using-setinterval) which are helpful in telling me I need to use setInterval, but because I am a beginner I am not sure how to implement it with the code I have. I tried updating the miliseconds set in the counter variable but that didn't change anything.

Here is the hover code so far. It advances the image on hover but not continuously.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var thumbs = $('ul.thumbHolder li');
        var bigImgs = $('ul.imgHolder li');
        var mask = $('.imgHolder');
        var imgW = $('ul.imgHolder li').width();
        var speed = 800;

        thumbs.removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');

        thumbs.click(function () {
        var target = $(this).index();

        mask.animate({
        'left': '-' + imgW * target + 'px'
        }, speed);


        thumbs.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        });


        $('.Bleft').on('mouseover', function () {
            var i = $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').index();
            i--;

            $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
            thumbs.eq(i).addClass('selected');

            if (i === -1) {
                mask.animate({
                    'left': '-' + imgW * $('ul.thumbHolder li').index() + 'px'
                }, speed);
            } else {
                mask.animate({
                    'left': '-' + imgW * i + 'px'
                }, speed);
            }
            clearInterval(counter);
        });

        $('.Bright').on('mouseover', function () {
        var i = $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').index();
        i = i >= thumbs.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;

        $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        thumbs.eq(i).addClass('selected');

        mask.animate({
        'left': '-' + imgW * i + 'px'
        }, speed);
        clearInterval(counter);
        });
        var count = 0;
        var counter = window.setInterval(timer, 5000);

        function timer() {
        count = count + 0;
        if (count >= 0) {
        count = 0;
        return;
        }
        mask.animate({
        'left': '-' + imgW * count + 'px'
        }, speed);
        thumbs.removeClass('selected');
        thumbs.eq(count).addClass('selected');
        }

        });
```

[This is an example of what I am trying to achieve](http://www.bloomingdales.com/fashion-index/reiss-spring-2013.jsp) (I know it is flash but I think it can be done with jQuery too). 

[This is a fiddle that has all my work so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/s7b4Y/)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am close to the solution. This is my idea.
Every `ul.imgHolder li` is divided in many blocks of 20px ( you can change the size of course ), so if a div has a size of 980px you will have 49 blocks for image.

When mouseover event is fired I will slide for a block every `speed` milliseconds until the mouseout is fired.

I've implemented only the slide right button, I've deleted partially some logic, sorry!

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$(document).ready(function(){
var thumbs = $('ul.thumbHolder li');
var bigImgs = $('ul.imgHolder li');
var mask = $('.imgHolder');
var imgW = $('ul.imgHolder li').width(); //Assuming imgW % 20 = 0
var blockSize = 20; //20px
var blocksPerThumb = imgW/blockSize;
var numBlocks = (blocksPerThumb)*thumbs.length;
var speed = 400;
var blockPos = 0;
var currentAnim = null;

thumbs.removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');

thumbs.click(function () {
    var target = $(this).index();

    mask.animate({
        'left': '-' + imgW * target + 'px'
    }, speed,'linear');


    thumbs.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});


$('.Bleft').on('mouseover', function () {

});

$('.Bright').on('mouseover', function(){
    currentAnim = setInterval(goRight,speed);
}).mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(currentAnim);
});

var goRight =  function () {
    blockPos = (blockPos+1)%numBlocks;

    mask.animate({
        'left': '-' + blockSize * blockPos + 'px'
    }, speed,'linear');

};

});
```

Good Work!