# onmouseover and onmouseout setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have been stuck with this problem. I am using slider for my app. For sliding the app I am using [splide-js](https://splidejs.com/getting-started/). My image slider works fine.

I have connected my slider with my `li` elements. I want to make custom `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events. When the user triggers `mouseover` on `li` it will pause and when `mouseout` it will resume the slide.

I was checking this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512835/animate-continuously-onmouseover-using-setinterval) and tried to do logic like the person by using `setinterval` but could not able to do that.

```js
const autoPlay = false;
const pauseOnHover = document.getElementById('pause');

function nextSlide() { //I don't what kind logic I should use to pause the slide

}

let  timer = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide();
}, 400);


pauseOnHover.onmouseover = () => {
  if( autoPlay) {
    timer
  }
}
pauseOnHover.onmouseout = () => {
  if (autoPlay) {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='checklist' id="pause">
  <ol>
    <li id="link-1">Assign jobs in an instant.</li>
    <li id="link-2">Always see what's happening.</li>
    <li id="link-3">Easy to set-up & use.</li>
    <li id="link-4">Be more sustainable</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `autoplay : true, pauseOnHover:false` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please intilaize and reintiliaze the interval on mousehover, onmouseout if interval exists cancel it.

Please try below code.

```js
const autoPlay = false;
const pauseOnHover = document.getElementById('pause');

function nextSlide() {
  //For example I have put console.log, you mat put any code block here.
  console.log("hello");
}

let timer;


pauseOnHover.onmouseover = () => {

  autoplay = true;
  if (!autoPlay) {
    autoplay = true;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      nextSlide();
    }, 400);
  }
}
pauseOnHover.onmouseout = () => {

  autoplay = false;
  timer && clearInterval(timer)

}
```

```html
<div class='checklist' id="pause">
  <ol>
    <li id="link-1">Assign jobs in an instant.</li>
    <li id="link-2">Always see what's happening.</li>
    <li id="link-3">Easy to set-up & use.</li>
    <li id="link-4">Be more sustainable</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a `pauseOnHover` option / property on splide. While creating splide, if OP makes that propery true, then OP easily achieve what he wants ;) no need of extra code

Comment: My answer is to fix in JS way for 'onmouseover and onmouseout setInterval'. Yeah if there are APIs to fix the problem, thats good to know.

Comment: Yes I saw that `pauseOnHover` options but I did not get how to use them in my `ul` elements. This is my splide logic. 

`const splide = new Splide('.mobile-splide', {
    type: 'loop',
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 3000,
    perPage: 1
  }).mount();`

Comment: Yes I agree with @Sivakumar